# Flutter: Get the exact position/offset of a word or the line containing the word inside a long paragraph currently shown in the UI

Tags: string, flutter, search, line, offset

I'm trying to display **markdown** data in a Flutter app using the `flutter_markdown` package. I've implemented that using the `markdown` widget and added a `scrollController` to it to show long paragraphs but now, I need to add the feature of **searching word(s) on the page**. Something similar to the search feature in a PDF reader or in a browser. We normally use the feature by pressing `ctrl` + `f`.

So, whenever a user will search for a word, I need to know the offset/position of that searched word on the screen or the line containing the word so that I can pass the offset/position value to the `scrollController` to take the user to that line of the paragraph.

Can anyone tell me how can I get the offset value of a word or line containing the word in a long paragraph currently showing on the screen?